# Select id específico em campo multiplo array

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um campo no BD que gravo os ID vindo de um select multiplo.
Os registros ficam salvos conforme exemplo abaixo:

`1,5,7,10`

Agora preciso fazer um select com a condição de verificar se um certo ID está dentro desta variavel, exemplo:

```
SELECT ID FROM usuario WHERE idpermitido = 5
```

Ou seja, só me retorne registro se o ID "5" esta autorizado acessar

Comment: `...WHERE ID IN (idpermitido)`, seria isso que deseja? Se o id do usuario está na lista de ids permitidos?

Comment: somente IN ( ) só dá certo se no campo conter somente o ID "5" sozinho. Porém no campo está salvo varios ID separados por virgula  porque vem de um select multiplo, e tenho que saber se o ID que procuro está ali dentre os demais

Comment: não tenho certeza se é a melhor alternativa mas talvez se vc fizer um select desse campo dar um ```$array = explode(',', $result); var_dump(in_array($id, $array))```

Comment: Obrigado Samuel, mas seria o ideal mesmo ja na consulta validar este campo

Comment: converter para array é a melhor opção, porque usar por exemplo `LOCATE("5",idpermid) >0`, mas se houver numeros com 5 em qualquer posição, como "55, 15, 254, etc" também vai localizar, ou então um "código feio", que seria  `LOCATE(",5,",idpermid) >0`  :D

Comment: Usar campo múltiplos não é recomendado, talvez faça sentido no seu caso, mas isso é contra a primeira forma normal. Se quiser fazer assim, você pode usar o formato JSON e fazer o decode na busca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De forma bem groseira, isso aqui funcionaria

```
SELECT ID FROM usuario WHERE idpermitido LIKE '%,5,%';
```

Mas tem muitos meios de melhorar essa sua tabela aí, uma delas é criando outra tabela que associa o id do usuário ao id da permissão dele, dai era só fazer um INNER JOIN com a tabela de usuário e pegar o que quiser